# Regex for extracting name starting with Mr.|Mrs

Tags: python, regex, findall

I was trying to write regex for identifying name starting with

```
Mr.|Mrs.
```

for example

```
Mr. A, Mrs. B.
```

I tried several expressions. These regular expressions were checked on online tool at [pythonregex.com](http://www.pythonregex.com/). The test string used is:

```
"hey where is Mr A how are u Mrs. B tt`"
```

Outputs mentioned are of `findall()` function of Python, i.e.

```
regex.findall(string)
```

Their respective outputs with `regex` are below.

```
Mr.|Mrs. [a-zA-Z]+  o/p-[u'Mr ', u'Mrs']
```

why A and B are not appearing with Mr. and Mrs.?

```
[Mr.|Mrs.]+ [a-zA-Z]+ o/p-[u's Mr', u'. B']
```

Why s is coming with Mr. instead of A?

I tried many more combinations but these are confusing so here are they. For name part I know regex has to cover more conditions but was starting from basic.

Comment: `[Mr.|Mrs.]+` totally wrong.

Comment: dot has special meaning in regex. Escape it `\.` better use `Mrs?\.`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Have you typed in the test string correctly?   Your Mr A does not have a dot in the test string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your regex like below,

```
(?:Mr\.|Mrs\.) [a-zA-Z]+
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xB4zQ3/1)

1. You need to put `Mr\.`, `Mrs\.` inside a non-capturing or capturing group , so that the `|` (OR) applies to the group itself.
2. You must need to escape the dot in your regex  to match a literal dot or otherwise, it would match any character. `.` is a special meta character in regex which matches any character except line breaks.

**OR**

Even shorter one,

```
Mrs?\. [a-zA-Z]+
```

`?` quantifier in the above makes the previous character `s` as an optional one.

Comment: Thanks. It is quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There's a python library for parsing human names :

https://github.com/derek73/python-nameparser

Much better than writing your own regex.

Comment: I'm learning this to use in other languages as well. but thanks for your suggestion. :)